# Strange way to reverse a string with recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I found this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 

int f(int c) { 
    static int b;

    if (isspace(c))
        return b = c & '\n';

    f(getchar()); 

    return putchar(c) == b && f(c); 
} 

int main(void) { 
   return f(0); 
}
```

I want to understand how this code works, I never saw this type of code so elaborate, what is it for `c & '\n'` why this comparison `putchar(c) == b`?

Someone help me understand this?

Comment: Seems rather awkward code. `c & '\n'` is a bitwise and operator on '\n' which is effectively decimal 10 or binary 1010. It is then setting global variable b to that.

Comment: Where did you find this code? I would think it would block on `f(getchar());` in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

c & '\n' is only called when isspace is true, the value calculated is stored in variable 'b' which is static so it will carry both forwards and backwards through the recursive stack as it expands and contracts.

I had to look isspace up and found: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm
which shows there are 6 characters matched by isspace.

The & is a bitwise AND, which will return a value with bits set only if the bits in both parameters are enabled (1).

Going through the values from isspace we get:

- 0x20 (space) AND 0x0a (\n) gives 0 (\0) string terminator
- 0x09 (tab) gives 0x08 (backspace)
- 0x0a (newline) gives 0x0a (newline)
- 0x0b (vertical tab) gives 0x0a again
- 0x0c (feed) gives 0x08 again
- 0x0d (carriage return) gives 0x08 again

Looking at this, I would say the desired result were probably the terminator for space and the newline for newline characters.  I would guess that the other results were not desired or anticipated, and the tab to backspace conversion will probably cause the function to produce very strange output when tabs are in the input stream.

Overall this is a dumb way to design code and may be part of an entry for the [obfuscated C competition](http://www.ioccc.org/) where such things are applauded.  Picking it apart in detail may teach you some very important things about the C language, but this is not something you should ever aim to use in production code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct program; there is an infinite recursion if its input doesn't contain a character for which PeteB found `b` to become nonzero (`\t` `\n` `\v` `\f` `\r`) - try `… </dev/null`.